# email excel active sheet as a pdf with other attachments

Tags: vba, excel

I using a macro VBA script in excel that allows me to email the active range to a recipient as a pdf.

here's the code

```
Sub AttachActiveSheetPDF()
  Dim IsCreated As Boolean
  Dim i As Long
  Dim PdfFile As String, Title As String
  Dim OutlApp As Object

  ' Not sure for what the Title is
  Title = Range("A1")

  ' Define PDF filename
  PdfFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
  i = InStrRev(PdfFile, ".")
  If i > 1 Then PdfFile = Left(PdfFile, i - 1)
  PdfFile = PdfFile & "_" & ActiveSheet.Name & ".pdf"

  ' Export activesheet as PDF
  With ActiveSheet
    .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PdfFile,     Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False,     OpenAfterPublish:=False
  End With

  ' Use already open Outlook if possible
  On Error Resume Next
  Set OutlApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
  If Err Then
    Set OutlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    IsCreated = True
  End If
  OutlApp.Visible = True
  On Error GoTo 0

  ' Prepare e-mail with PDF attachment
  With OutlApp.CreateItem(0)

    ' Prepare e-mail
    .Subject = Title
    .To = "email@email.com" ' <-- Put email of the recipient here
    .CC = "" ' <-- Put email of 'copy to' recipient here
    .Body = "ùìåí øá," & vbLf & vbLf _
          & "øö''á ãå''ç òìåéåú îùìçú (îùåòø) ìàéùåø éåúí." & vbLf & vbLf _
          & "ááøëä," & vbLf _
          & Application.UserName & vbLf & vbLf
    .Attachments.Add PdfFile

    ' Try to send
    On Error Resume Next
    .Send
    Application.Visible = True
    If Err Then
      MsgBox "E-mail was not sent", vbExclamation
    Else
      MsgBox "E-mail successfully sent", vbInformation
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

  End With

  ' Delete PDF file
  Kill PdfFile

  ' Quit Outlook if it was created by this code
  If IsCreated Then OutlApp.Quit

  ' Release the memory of object variable
  Set OutlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

now I need this code to do the same and convert the active range to PDf but I also need to allow me to select and add other file as attachments to the email as well, my VBA and excel macro skills are not that great and I have no idea how to do that. could you please help me and rewrite the the code to do want I need.
Thanks,
Dan.

Comment: Did you even *try* it on your own? I mean you have the `.Attachments.Add PdfFile` command in your code that obviously adds an attachment (your PDF). With a little research you find eg the [`FileDialog` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.filedialog) to pick a file and you can use it for selecting and adding any file as attachment too. Give it a try. If you get stuck or errors come back, update your code in the question and ask a question to what you tried. • Otherwise your question is just like asking us to do the work for you.

Comment: This is not my code, I had no idea where to begin my vba skills are poor

Comment: Well then try it now. Do some research and give it a try. It's a good time now to start improving your skills by reading tutorials and documentations of these two commands.

Answer (score 0):

You should change this section:

```
On Error Resume Next
.Send
Application.Visible = True
If Err Then
  MsgBox "E-mail was not sent", vbExclamation
Else
  MsgBox "E-mail successfully sent", vbInformation
End If
```

To:

```
.Save
.Close olPromptForSave
Application.Visible = True
```

This will save the email in your **drafts** folder so you can add more attachments

Comment: that was a great idea. Thank you.